# Use MFA Hardware Token with Identity Framework Experience

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am currently using Phone Based MFA with Custom Flows created using Identity Framework Experience. How would I extend this to use Hardware Tokens, or App based authenticators like Google or Microsoft Authenticator.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend your MFA using [Hardware OATH tokens in Azure MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-authentication-methods#oath-hardware-tokens-public-preview)

As Microsoft Previews Hardware OATH Tokens with Azure Multi factor Authentication.

**Requirements:**

> The following are the pre-requirements to complete this [configuration](https://www.token2.com/shop/page/classic-hardware-tokens-for-office-365-azure-cloud-multi-factor-authentication):
>
> - Azure AD Premium P1 or P2 license
> - Token2 hardware token(s)
> - A CSV file for your token device(s). You will receive an email with    the CSV you confirm the delivery*

**Devices For CSV**

As I don't have device right now that's why I am using virtual device emulator refer [here](https://www.token2.com/site/page/totp-toolset)

You have to create a secret with this device. The secret is required for upload to Azure AD and is required in the form of a CSV file with six columns:

Secret would be look like this below:

[image]

This CSV file must contain following information:

> upn,serial number,secret key,timeinterval,manufacturer,model

Which should match with azure portal like below information:

[image]

> Ensure each UPN in the first column matches the device you are issuing
>   to the user and upload the CSV file to Azure AD.
>
> This is done from **Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory left menu >
>   MFA (in Security area) > OAUTH tokens** (in settings area)

**Upload CSV**

Once you have created your csv file from the given emulator which has [given above](https://www.token2.com/site/page/totp-toolset)

You have to upload your file on azure portal.

> **CSV format**
>
> upn,serial number,secret key,timeinterval,manufacturer,model
>   gulnara@token2.onmicrosoft.com,60234567,1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef,30,Token2,c101
>
> **Note:**  Make sure you include the header row in your CSV file as shown above. Also, please do not edit the CSV file in Excel  use a
>   text editor (Notepad) instead

**Click Upload and browse for your CSV file**. As long as there are no errors it will upload fine. Errors are displayed in the notifications area. Once the upload is complete click Refresh to see the imported hardware tokens. Tokens assigned to users that do not exist will appear after the user is created, if the user is created within 30 days

**Then you just need to activate the hardware token by clicking Activate**

See the screen shot below

[image]

Once you have activated soon the verification code prompted like below:

[image]

**Once OATH token is activated and set as the default MFA method, users can use it to log in. Like below**

[image]

> **Please note** that the login page will still ask for "authenticator app"
>   code on the login page, but the OTP generated by the hardware token
>   will for sure be accepted without any issues.

Now Enter the code from the hardware or your [emulator](https://www.token2.com/site/page/totp-toolset). The token changes every 30 seconds and is valid for a short while either side of the time it is displayed for on the device.

See the screen shot:

[image]

> For large organization they can also set up additional MFA methods in
>   addition to the hardware tokens. This will ensure users can still log
>   in in case the hardware token is lost or damaged. Additional MFA
>   factors, such as SMS or mobile app can be configured by users
>   themselves on [this page](https://aka.ms/mfasetup).

Like below:

[image]

If you need more information you could refer [here](https://osddeployment.dk/2018/11/03/how-to-use-oath-hardware-tokens-with-azuread-for-mfa/)

Microsoft reference check [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/Hardware-OATH-tokens-in-Azure-MFA-in-the-cloud-are-now-available/ba-p/276466)

Hardware token device information refer [here](https://www.token2.com/home)

Comment: @Douglas Woods You could try this workaround. Thanks